# Como puedo evitar que se muestre el error 404 en la consola de una imagen

Tags: javascript, html

buen dia... como puedo evitar que se muestre los errores en la consola, respecto a que no a encontrado una URL de la imagen? intente con esto

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'https://www.googlke.com', true);
        request.send();
        if (request.status === 0) {
            $('#contenedor_producto').html('<img src="/Imagenes/03Cuaderno.jpg" />');
        }
```

(Si me funciona el poner la imagen, pero el error en consola se segui mostrando)
Lo que quiero es que si detecta que hay un error en la URL que haga una accion pero que no muestre el error en consola, existira alguna manera?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que puedes utilizar un bloque try catch para capturar el error y personalizar lo que quieras que se muestre en la consola